# Installing Wamp on Windows 7: CLI not working

Tags: php, wamp, command-line-interface, wampserver

I'm trying to install WampServer on Windows 7, but at the end of the installation it says "CLI has stopped working". I don't know what it means and I'm stuck, and the server is not even working.

Can someone help, please?

Many thanks

Comment: This is not a programming question, StackOverflow is not the right place to get software support.

Comment: More than likely you have another php installation somewhere !

Comment: @Dan Grossman: Ok. Point me to where I can ask those type of questions

Comment: http://www.superuser.com